# UnsatisfiedLinkError using openjdk:17 inside Docker container

Tags: java, docker, shared-libraries, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I want to Dockerize a web application, which works perfectly fine locally. When trying to run the application inside Docker, an UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown when invoking a function from the Nauty library.

To work with this library locally, the Spring application has to be started by doing

```
java -Djava.library.path="<PATH>/backend/lib/" -jar backend.jar
```

This library path points to the directory where the Nauty library (libnauty.so) resides. In my ~/.bashrc, I also had to set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<PATH>/backend/lib/:/usr/local/lib`. After making these two changes, the application works fine and functions from the Nauty library can be invoked without any problems.

After Dockerizing the application, I get the following error when invoking a library function

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nauty in java.library.path: "/home/backend/lib/"
```

However, the libnauty.so file is copied to the Docker container and is present in /home/backend/lib directory. I also set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the Docker container. The issue however still remains.

I use docker-compose to set up the application. The Dockerfile for the back-end looks like this.

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/backend/lib/:/usr/local/lib
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /home/backend/backend.jar
COPY . /home/backend
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.library.path=\"/home/backend/lib/\"", "-jar", "/home/backend/backend.jar"]
```

Any pointers to how this issue could be solved would be greatly appreciated. I have looked around for quite some time now, but I can't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of googling and debugging, the problem was the double quotes around the library path in the ENTRYPOINT. The correct way to specify it is just

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.library.path=/home/backend/lib/", "-jar", "/home/backend/backend.jar"]
```